# Is there a tool to automatically generate view models from domain models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently using the ADO.NET DbContext Generator to generate domain objects from an entity model. Are there any tools that can generate a view model for each of the domain objects? Adding data annotations, like [Required], [DisplayName] and [DataType], to the view model properties would be nice too.

I'll be adding to these generated view models to build more complex view models but at least the most tedious work is automated.

ASP.NET MVC 4 RC

Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect the tool to know the `DisplayName` and all the rest...?

Comment: @gdoron, in my mind, `[Required]` and `[DataType]` can be derived from the column settings and `[DisplayName]` could be the column name split based on camel case. My request is really about getting the attributes added to the properties. I can manually tweak values, like the `[DisplayName]`, if I'm not satisfied with the generated values.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no such tools. It is up to you to define your view models. A tool cannot possibly know how your views look like and what information they contain. Remember that a view model could be the projection of multiple domain models. A tool can generate models from an existing database schema, but there's no such thing about view models. Their design is left to the ingenuousness of the developer and IMHO that's better.